# Android GCM Intent Service class name

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Does the GCMIntentService must be named like that?

And does it has to be located in my root package?

Where does this IntentService is getting called from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

> This intent service will be called by the GCMBroadcastReceiver (which
>   is provided by the GCM library), as shown in the next step. It must be
>   a subclass of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService, must
>   contain a public constructor, and should be named
>   my_app_package.GCMIntentService (unless you use a subclass of
>   GCMBroadcastReceiver that overrides the method used to name the
>   service).

As said in the link, is called from `GCMBroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

> Does the GCMIntentService must be named like that ?

Umm, yes..? If you are using [GCM helper library](http://developer.android.com/reference/gcm-packages.html). Because it's all tied up with that library so I think you should pretty much follow the steps on how to use it, mister :)

Comment: Also if you look at [GCM architectural overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) might show how to implement your own handling intent

Answer (score 0):

IntentService gets called by broadcast receiver. Broadcast receiver helps to receiving the push notification from android system. As when the message is arrived, android operating system broadcasts an announcement and our task is to catch that announcement and we will pass this announcement to **intent-service** so that we can further process the received json message.

Source: http://techlovejump.com/how-to-get-data-from-gcm-google-cloud-messaging-notification-in-android/